# Applying custom classes on Vuetify Data table columns

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using `Vuetify` in my project. My question is, is there any way to apply custom classes on **Vuetify Data table** column ?. I actually want to hide these specific columns in `print`.

```
data() {
    return {
      salaryId: "",
      search: "",
      paymentModal: false,
      paymentsModal: false,
      editModal: false,
      headers: [
        { text: "S#", value: "sno" },
        { text: "Staff Type", value: "staff_type" },
        { text: "Month", value: "month" },
        { text: "Salary", value: "amount" },
        { text: "Paid", value: "paid" },
        { text: "Balance", value: "balance" },
        { text: "Status", value: "status" },
        { text: "Pay Salary", value: "pay_salary" }, // this should not be in print
        { text: "Payments", value: "payments" },   // this should not be in print
        { text: "Actions", value: "actions" }  // this should not be in print
      ]
    };
  }
```

Comment: Use the item slot template

Comment: @Zim, could you example in answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the header properties to add a custom class to the headers:

```
headers: [{ text: "Pay Salary", value: "pay_salary", class: 'custom-class' }]
```

and use the slots to add a class to each cell

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
>
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
    <tr>
      <td class="custom-class">{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td class="custom-class">{{ item.age }}</td>
      <td class="custom-class">{{ item.country }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#data-tables

In order to hide a column, I know two solutions:

1. Filtering the headers array. Random example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  props: {
    hideColumns: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'Age', value: 'age' },
        { text: 'Country', value: 'country' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        { name: 'Lee', age: 45, country: 'EUA' },
        { name: 'Lin', age: 85, country: 'Japan' },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    newHeaders() {
      return this.headers.filter(({ value }) => !this.hideColumns.includes(value));
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="newHeaders"
      :items="desserts"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

2. Using the bootstrap classes:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: This is only adds a class to the header, not to every column below this header...

Comment: I edited the post. Thanks, @trainoasis :)

Answer (score 0):

**For Vuetify 3**

You can use `headerProps` and `cellProps` within `headers`, for instance:

```
headers: [
  {
    title: "Name",
    key: "name",
    headerProps: { // it will affect to the rendered <th> element
      class: "myclass", // can also be an array of strings
    },
    cellProps: { // it will affect to the rendered <td> elements
      class: "myclass", // can also be an array of strings
    },
  },
]
```

Ref: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-headers

**For Vuetify 2**

You can use `class` and `cellClass` within `headers`, for instance:

```
headers: [
  {
    text: "Name",
    value: "name",
    class: "myclass", // affects to <th> element; can be array of strings
    cellClass: "myclass", // affects to <td> elements; can be array of strings
  },
]
```

Ref: https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-headers